# How to bring a data kind to the value level?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have something like this in my code:

```
data SomeKind = Kind1 | Kind2 deriving Eq

data SomeValue (t :: SomeKind) = SomeValue

someValue1 :: SomeValue Kind1
someValue1 = SomeValue

someValue2 :: SomeValue Kind2
someValue2 = SomeValue
```

I want to get the kind that's in the type level to the value level, perhaps something like:

```
valueKind :: SomeValue a -> SomeKind
```

that will:

```
valueKind someValue1 == Kind1
valueKind someValue2 == Kind2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: just to be sure - you use `Kind` not in the `* -> *` sense right? Aside from that search for *type level functions* (in Haskell) - you can do quite a lot but we don't have full dependent types in Haskell (yet?)

Comment: @Carsten You're correct; the kind for SomeValue is `SomeKind -> *`.

Comment: You might find what you need in [this answer about a `Kindable` class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291740/is-it-possible-to-get-the-kind-of-a-type-constructor-in-haskell/26293317#26293317)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`valueKind :: SomeValue a -> SomeKind` is not possible. The `a` type parameter isn't present runtime in any shape or form, so we can't branch on it.

The standard method for making use of types both at runtime and compile time is to make so-called singleton types. Singletons are indexed by the type-level version of the original type, and have the property that we can reveal the index by pattern matching on them:

```
data SSomeKind (i :: SomeKind) where
  SKind1 :: SSomeKind Kind1
  SKind2 :: SSomeKind Kind2
```

They're called singletons because for each type index there is only a single value. Similarly, for each value there is only a single choice of type index. This correspondence lets us use `SSomeKind` as a runtime representation of `SomeKind`.

```
valueKind' :: SSomeKind a -> SomeKind
valueKind' SKind1 = Kind1
valueKind' SKind2 = Kind2
```

Creating singleton definitions and associated lifting and lowering functions is a rather mechanical job. The [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library automates and streamlines it. In our case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d| data SomeKind = Kind1 | Kind2  |])
-- generates a lot of stuff, including the SSomeKind definition.

-- works the same as our previously defined function
valueKind' :: SSomeKind a -> SomeKind
valueKind' = fromSing

-- we can also polymorphically get specific singleton values:
foo :: Sing Kind1
foo = sing -- now foo equals SKind1
```

There's a lot more in the library. See [this page](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons) for a quick start and further references.

Answer (score 7):

If you can tolerate a type class constraint, this can be accomplished with instances for each of the kinds in `SomeKind`. This is very similar to the `Kindable` typeclass

```
class SomeKindable (k :: SomeKind) where
    someKindOf :: p k -> SomeKind

instance SomeKindable Kind1 where
    someKindOf _ = Kind1

instance SomeKindable Kind2 where
    someKindOf _ = Kind2

valueKind ::  SomeKindable a => SomeValue a -> SomeKind
valueKind = someKindOf
```

The compiler can't tell that for all `k :: SomeKind` there is a `SomeKindable k` instance. If you need this to be available for every `SomeValue` without being able to show `SomeKindable` you can package up the value along with a `SomeKindable` dictionary in a `GADT`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data SomeValue (t :: SomeKind) where
    SomeValue :: SomeKindable t => SomeValue t

valueKind :: SomeValue a -> SomeKind
valueKind (p@SomeValue) = someKindOf p
```

Comment: This is the same idea as behind [`natVal :: KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-level-literals.html), right?

Comment: @Turion Yes, it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a type-class that returns the associated value based on the type-parameter.

```
class ValueKind (t :: SomeKind) where
    valueKind :: f t -> SomeKind

instance ValueKind Kind1 where
    valueKind _ = Kind1

instance ValueKind Kind2 where
    valueKind _ = Kind2
```